# npm publish unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-publish

I got the below error on call `npm publish`. I was trying publish an existing package on private feed:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "version": "0.0.6",
  "description": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "types": "./types/index.d.ts",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "engines": {
    "cordovaDependencies": {
      "0.2.3": {
        "cordova": ">=3.1.0"
      },
      "4.0.0": {
        "cordova": ">100"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, its happened because of the "engines" group in package.json. I removed it, and npm publish works.